# Using video stream as open GL ES 2.0 texture

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, google-cardboard

I'm trying to capture video and display it to the screen by setting an Open GL ES texture to an android `surfaceTexture`. I can't use a `TextureView` and implement `SurfaceTextureListener` as per [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_textureview.htm) since I am using Google Cardboard.

I have followed [the Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/draw.html) on how to initialise Open GL ES 2.0 and use it, and also [this tutorial](http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-four-introducing-basic-texturing/) on texturing.

Putting the 2 together I get a blank screen and occasionally get `<core_glBindTexture:572>: GL_INVALID_OPERATION` in the console window.

Overwhelmed by so many new concepts that I don't know, I'm not able to debug or just understand if the two approach can be used like this. Here is my drawing code, it is initialised in the `onSurfaceCreated()` of the `MainActivity` class, and drawn from `onEyeDraw()` which is Cardboard's draw function.

```
package com.example.rich.test3;

import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.view.TextureView;

import java.nio.ShortBuffer;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;

/**
 * Created by rich on 03/05/2015.
 */
public class Square {

private java.nio.FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
private java.nio.ShortBuffer drawListBuffer;
private final java.nio.FloatBuffer mCubeTextureCoordinates;

float color[] = { 1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.0f };

private final String vertexShaderCode =
        "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
        "attribute vec2 a_TexCoordinate;" +
        "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;" +
                "void main() {" +
                " gl_Position = vPosition;" +
                " v_TexCoordinate = a_TexCoordinate;" +
                "}";

private final String fragmentShaderCode =
        "precision mediump float;" +
                "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
                "uniform sampler2D u_Texture;" +
                "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;" +
                "void main() {" +
                "gl_FragColor = (texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate));" +
                "}";

// number of coordinates per vertex in this array
static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
static float squareCoords[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom right
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   // top left
        0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f}; // top right

private short drawOrder[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 }; // order to draw vertices

private int mProgram;

private int mPositionHandle;
private int mColorHandle;
private int mTextureUniformHandle;
private int mTextureCoordinateHandle;
private final int mTextureCoordinateDataSize = 2;

private final int vertexCount = squareCoords.length / COORDS_PER_VERTEX;
private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex

private int mTextureDataHandle;

float textureCoordinates[] =
        {0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f };

Camera _camera;
TextureView _textureView;
int[] textures;
android.graphics.SurfaceTexture _surface;

public Square()
{
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
            // (# of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
            squareCoords.length * 4);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(squareCoords);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    // initialize byte buffer for the draw list
    ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
            // (# of coordinate values * 2 bytes per short)
            drawOrder.length * 2);
    dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
    drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder);
    drawListBuffer.position(0);

    mCubeTextureCoordinates = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(textureCoordinates.length * 4)
            .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
    mCubeTextureCoordinates.put(textureCoordinates).position(0);

    // create empty OpenGL ES Program
    mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

    textures = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);

    _surface = new android.graphics.SurfaceTexture(textures[0]);
    _camera = Camera.open();
    Camera.Size previewSize = _camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();

    try
    {
        _camera.setPreviewTexture(_surface);
    }
    catch (java.io.IOException ex)
    {
        // Console.writeLine (ex.Message);
    }

    final int vertexShaderHandle = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLES20.glShaderSource(vertexShaderHandle, vertexShaderCode);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(vertexShaderHandle);
    final int[] compileStatus = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGetShaderiv(vertexShaderHandle, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0);
    if (compileStatus[0] == 0)
    {
        //do check here
    }

    final int fragmentShaderHandle = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    GLES20.glShaderSource(fragmentShaderHandle, fragmentShaderCode);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(fragmentShaderHandle);
    GLES20.glGetShaderiv(fragmentShaderHandle, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0);
    if (compileStatus[0] == 0)
    {
        //do check here
    }

    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShaderHandle);
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShaderHandle);
    GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(mProgram, 0, "a_Position");
    GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(mProgram, 0, "a_TexCoordinate");

    GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);
    final int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGetProgramiv(mProgram, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0);
    if (linkStatus[0] == 0)
    {
        //do check here
    }

    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    mTextureDataHandle = textures[0];

    // Set filtering
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
}

public void draw()
{
    _surface.updateTexImage();
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

    mTextureUniformHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "u_Texture");
    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "a_Position");
    mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "a_Color");
    mTextureCoordinateHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "a_TexCoordinate");

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureDataHandle);

    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            vertexStride, vertexBuffer);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTextureCoordinateHandle, mTextureCoordinateDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            0, mCubeTextureCoordinates);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTextureCoordinateHandle);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(mTextureUniformHandle, 0);

    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertexCount);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
}

}
```

Comment: Have you found https://github.com/google/grafika ?  The "texture from camera" activity probably does most of what you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When rendering a [SurfaceTexture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html) texture object, you need to use the `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES` texture target:

> The texture object uses the GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES texture target, which is defined by the GL_OES_EGL_image_external OpenGL ES extension. This limits how the texture may be used. Each time the texture is bound it must be bound to the GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES target rather than the GL_TEXTURE_2D target. Additionally, any OpenGL ES 2.0 shader that samples from the texture must declare its use of this extension using, for example, an "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require" directive. Such shaders must also access the texture using the samplerExternalOES GLSL sampler type.

So you need to change your fragment shader like this, adding the `#extension` declaration and declaring your texture uniform as `samplerExternalOES`:

```
private final String fragmentShaderCode =
    "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n" +
    "precision mediump float;" +
    "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
    "uniform samplerExternalOES u_Texture;" +
    "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;" +
    "void main() {" +
            "gl_FragColor = (texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate));" +
    "}";
```

Also in your `draw()` function, bind the texture like this:

```
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, mTextureDataHandle);
```

Comment: just had a chance to try it and get  W/Adreno-ES20﹕ <core_glBindTexture:572>: GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Comment: You can get that error if you bind to different targets: https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBindTexture.xml you are calling glBindTexture in the constructor as well as in draw(), change that to use GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES as well

Comment: well spotted. I now get this error W/Adreno-ES20﹕ <core_glVertexAttribPointer:533>: GL_INVALID_VALUE. google isn't coming up with anything. can you see anything that could be causing this?

Comment: I think you're passing an invalid value in mPositionHandle. Your call to glGetAttribLocation asks for "a_Position" but it's called "vPosition" in the shader. Same for "a_Color"/"vColor" (although you don't seem to be using it). You should be calling GetUniformLocation for the color because it's a uniform not an attribute.

Comment: thanks, i still get nothing but at least i know there are no errors now.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use normal texture to render camera or video preview, you have to use [GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_EGL_image_external.txt) extension. I had same problem and i found a complete working solution on github. The name of the project is android_instacam .

[Here](https://github.com/harism/android_instacam) you will find source code to study. If you want to see it in action directly on your device just go on play store [here](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fi.harism.instacam).